# regex capturing multiple words in between two chosen words python

Tags: python, regex, nlp

I new fairly new to regex and can't understand what I am doing wrong.

I have different tweets about women and am trying to capture sentences that contain words.

An example of a piece of text: 
`all women should be earning less within the workplace if you ask me`

and I a trying to capture `women should be earning less within the workplace` and have tried several regex patterns including:

```
women(\w+\W+\s*\S*)workplace
women(\w+\W+\s*\S*){2,}workplace
\bwomen(\w+\W+\s*\S*){2,}workplace\b
```

From my understanding this code should capture unlimited number of word characters, spaces or non-whitespace characters at least twice or more. I also used the boundary anchor to see if that would work but it didn't.

However I receive no matches for this at all. Could someone explain what I am doing wrong please.

Thanks.

Comment: Update the question to include the actual code you're using.

Comment: Do you want sentences that contain all phrases in a list of phrases such as ['women', 'should', 'earning less', 'workplace']?  Perhaps also some alterations of some phrases such as for 'earning less', being equivalent to:  'earning less', 'earn less', 'make less', 'paid less', etc.

Comment: What do wish to extract if the string were `"women should earn what women in the workplace deserve"`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland For my initial question, the capture would be `women should earn what women in the workplace`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are trying to capture everything between two keywords, try something like:

`\bwomen\b.*\bworkplace\b`

To capture the entire sentence that contains the two keywords, use something like:

`\b[^.?!]*?\bwomen\b.*?\bworkplace\b[^.?!]*\b`

This assumes that sentences are separated with `.`, `?`, or `!`. It will also incorrectly identify punctuation in abbreviations like `Ms.` as sentence boundaries.

Comment: Brilliant thanks. If i wanted to capture the word all with the sentence could I simply do this? - (\w+\s* women[^.]*workplace)

Comment: @geds133 Could you rephrase your question? Are you trying to capture the entire sentence that contains those two words?

Comment: My first question was the solution you gave. A side question i was curious on was how to capture the entire sentence

Comment: It's a bit trickier to detect sentence boundaries. I'll edit my answer with another regex string.

Comment: Your regex #2 matches `"women. See them in the workspace"` in the string `"Two strong women. See them in the wordspace."`. I believe that `(?<=^|[.?!] )[^.?!\r\n]*\bwomen\b[^.?!\r\n]*\bworkplace\b[^.?!\r\n]*[.?!]` would work. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/JbtRLL/5/). Unfortunately, Python's re module does not allow lookbehinds (`(?<=^|[.?!] )` being a *positive lookbehind*) to support alternations (or be variable-width). I tested it with the PCRE regex engine, which here gives the same results as would the use of Python's alternative "PyPI" [regex engine](https://pypi.org/project/regex/).

Comment: Whenever you give a regex solution you should test it with an online regex engine (such as the Python option at [regex101](https://regex101.com/) or at [tutorials point](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python_online.php) and provide a link (generated by the site) that shows your regex in use with example strings.